# Finance tracking using Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have what seems to be a simple problem but I can't get it correct.  What I want to do is enter a Date and then a balance for each of the accounts listed below in the dictionary.  After that I want to SUM the total.  Seems simple enough but I am making a mess of it.   Any ideas how to make this work?  I know I want to use a Dictionary for this, as I intend to add onto this as I go along (add more accounts, or another key/value pair etc).

Thanks!

```
savings = {'month': '' ['HSA': 0, 'BofA': 0, 'RothIRA': 0]}

for item in savings:
    month = input('Enter current month: ')
    balance = int(input('Enter balance for: '{savings}))
    savings[month][savings] = balance
print(savings)
print('Total savings for the month is: 'sum(balance) + 'dollars')
```

Comment: It would be better to use a class imo

Comment: You mean, you have syntax errors and you want to fix that or you can't get the logic correct? Because, I can see few errors in syntax.

Comment: @RetardedJoker I think I more or less have the logic correct (but not perfect) but I know it's loaded with syntax errors.  The suggestion of using a class may be a good one too as diek mentioned but I am not sure how to approach that.  Thanks

Comment: This isn't a minimum functional example. It won't run because of syntax errors. Can you please fix those up, and provide examples where your code doesn't behave as expected, and what behaviour you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way may be is to go with a class as mentioned. However, to cater the simple needs, here goes

```
savings = {'month': {'HSA':0, 'BofA':0, 'RothIRA':0}};

for item in savings:
    month = input("Enter current month: ");
    monat = savings.get(month);
    accNames = list(monat.keys());
print(accNames);

for s in range(len(accNames)):
    balance = int(input("Enter balance for "+accNames[s]+" : "));
    savings[month][accNames[s]] = balance;
print(savings[month]);    
print("Total is :" + str(int(savings[month][accNames[0]]+savings[month][accNames[1]]+savings[month][accNames[2]])) + "$");
```

While the implementation can well be improved further, Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @RussellB.  That helps.  I will try and take this and turn it into a class to see what that looks like